# Using posterior in an expectation

Tags: machine-learning, probability, bayesian, posterior, conditioning

I am studying (myself, not in class) the book of Rogers & Girolami, A First Course in Machine Learning.

In working through a logistic classifier, I found the equation 
$$
  p(t_{new} = 1| \mathbf{x}_{new}, \mathbf{X}, \mathbf{t}) 
      = E_{p(\mathbf{w}|\mathbf{X,t})} \left\{ \frac{1}{1 + \exp(-\mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{x}_{new})} \right\}
$$

So is this the expectation with respect to the posterior... of the probability of a new data point being 1?

I do not recognize this expression. Does it have a name?

My question: can someone describe this in a more generic form? For example is it equivalent
$$
  \int p(D=\text{const}|M)\, p(M|D)\, dM
$$
where $D$ is "data" and $M$ is "model" ?
If so, then the expression $\int p(D=\text{const}|M) dM $ does not integrate to 1 I think, it feels wrong.

Comment: The link goes to the wrong book on Amazon.

Comment: I removed the link. That is weird, I did not add the link. Maybe it is added auotmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Bayesian perspective, the predictive distribution is constructed by incorporating a new value of the observable $t_\text{new}$ as a part of the unknowns, hence aggregating it with the parameter $w$. The predictive distribution is thus derived by marginalising over the parameter:
$$p(t_\text{new}|{\cal D})=\int p(t_\text{new},w|{\cal D})\, \mathrm{d} w
\propto \int p(t_\text{new}|w)p({\cal D}|w) p(w)\, \mathrm{d} w$$
Hence, in the logistic case
$$pr(t_\text{new}=1|{\cal D})=\int pr(t_\text{new}=1,w|{\cal D})\, \mathrm{d} w \propto \int pr(t_\text{new}=1|w)p({\cal D}|w) p(w)\, \mathrm{d} w$$or
$$pr(t_\text{new}=1|{\cal D})=\mathbb{E}^\pi[pr(t_\text{new}=1|w)|{\cal D}]$$

Comment: There seems some typos, it should be : ∫p(tnew,w|D)dw∝∫p(tnew|w)p(w|D)dw
also, ∫ pr(tnew=1,w|D)dw∝∫pr(tnew=1|w)p(w|D)dw

Comment: @lynnjohn Right, the prior is not necessarily a flat prior.